# Unbale to send a request using fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch

I am using fetch to send a http request this is my code :

```
const fetch = require('fetch')

fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

however , I got this error :

> TypeError: fetch is not a function

Any guide is appreciated , thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch is not available in Node JS , you will have to use node-fetch.

[node-fetch npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

And then require it like this :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use "node-fetch"

Also try switching over to async-await; it's a lot better syntactically - Because node-fetch returns promises, you already know that :)

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Then inside some async function...

const response = await fetch(`${YOUR_API}`, {
        method: 'GET', // or POST or whatever
        headers: {
                "Some-key": "Some-value"
        }
});

const responseJson = await response.json();

// Apply exception handling
```

Answer (score -1):

remove this line

const fetch = require('fetch')

Comment: Nothing will happen by removing that line. Node doesnot have fetch , you will have to use node-fetch from npm.